# Excel - Using COUNTIF/COUNTIFS across multiple sheets/same column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to "COUNT" the number of a certain object in column I (in this instance) across multiple sheets. That value in column I is the result of a formula (if it matters). So far I have:

`=COUNTIF('Page M904'!I:I,A13)+COUNTIF('Page M905'!I:I,A13)+COUNTIF('Page M906'!I:I,A13)`

which works, but I am going to have 20 something pages to scan through. I would like to avoid having a page long formula.

I have tried

`=COUNTIFS('Page M904:Page M906'!I:I,A13)` and 
`=COUNTIF('Page M904:Page M906'!I:I,A13)`

but that results in a `#VALUE`.

And I think

`=COUNTIFS('Page M904'!I:I,A14,'Page M905'!I:I,A14,'Page M906'!I:I,A14)`

is a misapplication of the `COUNTIFS` because I get `0` when it should be 35.

I am trying to avoid using VBA for this application. But if has to be, then it has to be :) Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: `'Page M904:Page M906'!I:I` - good attempt, but unfortunatelly `Countif` doesn't support 3-D references..

Comment: `I am trying to avoid using VBA. But if has to be, then it has to be:)` - you could write quite simple user defined function for this.

Comment: `=COUNTIFS('Page M904'!I:I,A14,'Page M905'!I:I,A14,'Page M906'!I:I,A14)` returns 0 because in that phrasing it becomes `IF...AND`, rather than `IF...OR` as you want it.

Comment: Thanks everyone. The UDF is actually new to me, but I am still a noob after 20 years ;) Everyone here is great with their insight and tolerance of beginner level questions :D

Comment: You could simplify the formula a bit by Naming the Columns of those sheets. Say **M904i** for col **I** of **Page M904**. So `'Page M904'!I:I` becomes `M904i`. But still, there are 20+ of this naming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am trying to avoid using VBA. **But if has to be, then it has to be**:)

There is quite simple UDF for you:

```
Function myCountIf(rng As Range, criteria) As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        myCountIf = myCountIf + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range(rng.Address), criteria)
    Next ws
End Function
```

and call it like this: `=myCountIf(I:I,A13)`

---

P.S. if you'd like to exclude some sheets, you can add `If` statement:

```
Function myCountIf(rng As Range, criteria) As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.name <> "Sheet1" And ws.name <> "Sheet2" Then
            myCountIf = myCountIf + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range(rng.Address), criteria)
        End If
    Next ws
End Function
```

**UPD:**

> I have four "reference" sheets that I need to exclude from being scanned/searched. They are currently the last four in the workbook

```
Function myCountIf(rng As Range, criteria) As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 4
        myCountIf = myCountIf + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range(rng.Address), criteria)
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: I have four "reference" sheets that I need to exclude from being scanned/searched. They are currently the last four in the workbook and will remain in that place. Can that code be changed to exclude those four sheets?

Comment: stupid question... how do I get the UDF to work. I get a `#NAME?` error. Macros are enabled.

Comment: you should create new module and place UDF in it. How to create module see in this image: http://webum.by/images/blog/2013/05/excel-vba-access-bd/03-insetr-module.png

Comment: My first response would've been "What is this 'module' you speak of?" but I saw the pic, followed that and it WORKS! Many thanks and respek.

Answer (score 11):

This could be solved without VBA by the following technique.

In this example I am counting all the threes (3) in the range `A:A` of the sheets `Page M904`, `Page M905` and `Page M906`.

List all the sheet names in a single continuous range like in the following example. Here listed in the range `D3:D5`.

[image]

Then by having the lookup value in cell `B2`, the result can be found in cell `B4` by using the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&D3:D5&"'!A:A"), B2))
```

Comment: Thanks Søren, but I am going with the VBA/UDF method. I didn't know about UDFs but now I do and it seems simpler. I definitely appreciate the assistance. :D

Answer (score 2):

My first post... 
UDF I managed quickly to compile.
Usage:
Select 3D range as normal and enclose is into quotation marks like below...

=CountIf3D("'StartSheet:EndSheet'!G16:G878";"Criteria")

Advisably sheets to be adjacent to avoid unanticipated results.

```
Public Function CountIf3D(SheetstoCount As String, CriteriaToUse As Variant)

     Dim sStarSheet As String, sEndSheet As String, sAddress As String
     Dim lColonPos As Long, lExclaPos As Long, cnt As Long

    lColonPos = InStr(SheetstoCount, ":") 'Finding ':' separating sheets
    lExclaPos = InStr(SheetstoCount, "!") 'Finding '!' separating address from the sheets

    sStarSheet = Mid(SheetstoCount, 2, lColonPos - 2) 'Getting first sheet's name
    sEndSheet = Mid(SheetstoCount, lColonPos + 1, lExclaPos - lColonPos - 2) 'Getting last sheet's name

    sAddress = Mid(SheetstoCount, lExclaPos + 1, Len(SheetstoCount) - lExclaPos) 'Getting address

        cnt = 0
   For i = Sheets(sStarSheet).Index To Sheets(sEndSheet).Index
        cnt = cnt + Application.CountIf(Sheets(i).Range(sAddress), CriteriaToUse)
   Next

   CountIf3D = cnt

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do the same thing, and I have a work around that seems to be less complicated using the Frequency and Index functions. I use this part of the function from averaging over multiple sheets while excluding the all the 0's.

```
=(FREQUENCY(Start:End!B1,-0.000001)+INDEX(FREQUENCY(Start:End!B1,0),2))
```