# Applying COUNTIF over a defined range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Is it possible to use a COUNTIF spread over a range of tabs?
Currently my tab positioning is set as such:

Start Tab. End Tab.

I have a macro which creates a new tab and populates it with pre-filled data (from the user) and puts it between these 'start' and 'end' tabs.
Now one of the pieces of information the user enters is the type of program the client is joining (Medical, Supervisory Assistance etc.) This is denoted by MN and SA for example. This MN/SA fields are ALWAYS put in the same position on the spreadsheet B3. Hence I created my countif below:

COUNTIF('START:END!B3,"MN")

However I keep getting an #VALUE error. Is it because COUNTIF can't be applied over a range of tabs? I'd appreciate any advice. Thank you! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919461/excel-using-countif-countifs-across-multiple-sheets-same-column

Comment: Thanks Tim! All sorted :) 
I used the UDF supplied and substituted my information into this UDF. It's working as expected now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone wants to know what I did - I used the UDF code supplied in this link here: 
[Excel - Using COUNTIF/COUNTIFS across multiple sheets/same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919461/excel-using-countif-countifs-across-multiple-sheets-same-column)

And then substituted my arguments into the custom UDF.
=myCountIf(B3,"MN")