# Excel - Using COUNTIFS to count dates within a certain range across multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to "COUNT" the number of dates that fall between a certain date range over multiple sheets excluding the first 'Summary' sheet. Following other examples I have used:

```
=COUNTIFS('CWP-A1-Inst'!S7:S51,">=2015-09-13" _ 
         ,'CWP-A1-Inst'!S7:S51,"<=2015-09-19") _ 
+ COUNTIFS('CWP-A2-Inst'!V7:V51,">=2015-09-13" _ 
          ,'CWP-A2-Inst'!V7:V51,"<=2015-09-19") _ 
+ COUNTIFS('CWP-A3-Inst'!T7:T50,">=2015-09-13" _ 
          ,'CWP-A3-Inst'!T7:T50,"<=2015-09-19")
```

This method works but I have 28 sheets, 75 date ranges (each week starting with Sunday ending with Saturday for over a year) and 7 cost codes to fill this out for. It would take forever to change these all manually.

I have also tried the UDF suggested in another example -  [Excel - Using COUNTIF/COUNTIFS across multiple sheets/same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919461/excel-using-countif-countifs-across-multiple-sheets-same-column)  - but I am unable to figure out how to add the second set of criteria in the example as I am by no means a VB expert.

Thanks in advance for any recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this mod to the posted UDF link.

Edit:  code has been fixed so now it works.  I also added the "<=" into the function, so all you need to provide is the input dates as they are and nothing else.

```
Function myCountIf(rng As Range, startDate as Variant, endDate as Variant) As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        myCountIf = myCountIf + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range(rng.Address), "<=" & endDate) - WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range(rng.Address), "<=" & startDate)
    Next ws
End Function
```

And for startDate and endDate enter your criteria eg =myCountIf(A:A,">=2015-09-13","<=2015-09-19").

Comment: I have tried this and get a #VALUE? returned. All of the manually inputted dates are in column O on all 28 sheets. The dates I am referencing are on row 6 of the summary sheet, which are all Sundays. I tried entering my criteria as:

    =mycountif(O:O, ">=C6", "<D6")

where C6 is 2015-09-13 and D6 is 2015-09-20.

Comment: When excel sees ">=C6" it reads the whole thing as a string.  Instead, try ">=" & C6.  By doing that, it will concatenate the value from C6 with the ">=" operator.

Comment: I'm still getting  a #VALUE! after trying this. I am going to pick up a VB book to learn how to do this a little better. Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  Instead of doing StartDate as >= date, you should use <=.  Ok, I apologize for this being confusing, but the function is set to be Countif(Range, <=EndDate) - Countif(Range, <=StartDate), so that would give the range in between those two dates.

Comment: I figured it out.  Apparently doing that trick where I used the & _ to extend the line, excel didn't like that in this formula.  Removed that and it works.  I tested it on a spreadsheet I just made.

Comment: Added the <= into the function itself.  In your spreadsheet, all you need is =myCountIf(A:A,C6,D6).

Comment: Sadly this still isn't working. It returns a value of -30 with a single date entered. I also don't believe it is stepping through all of the sheets when I enter a range of $O:$O as it appears to be counting only the summary sheet where I am calling the function. I have gone back to copying and pasting my original function until I can figure out this more elegant solution. Thanks for everything. We'll get it yet!

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to get summary information about data when it is in a good structure.

If you had one big long list you would benefit from being able to use pivot tables   For examples see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=962r5nH7CHw)

If you were to take you data and put it in one long list this would be a good start (if the existing tables have the same structure).

Harvey