# How to write this faster?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

This is current formula
`=IF(Sheet1!A1="?","Check",IF(Sheet2!A2="?","Check",""))` (nested IF formula)

This is what formula should do: If any *A1* cell from *Sheet1* to *Sheet100* has *?* written in cell, than write in cell in which is this code  word *Check*.

**Question**
How to write fast this formula without having to type all 100 IF formulas? And if so, any tip to write them faster?
Best would be if we can skip VBA since I can't use it on android Excel version.
Thanx

Comment: Yes, that can be option.

Comment: since you don't want to / can't use VBA, have a look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919461/excel-using-countif-countifs-across-multiple-sheets-same-column.  reference the 2nd answer (the one w/ 8 upvotes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Sheet" & ROW(1:100) & "!A1"),"?"))
```

Comment: I was halfway through figuring this one out. I just knew when I hit refresh you or jeeped would have it. I'm learning just following you two around.

Comment: @JacobEdmond keep going and learning, you may get faster than me.  I learned most of what I know from here.

Comment: Very nice formula, i did not had that idea that @sous2817 proposed in my mind at all :) Thanx Scott Craner for answering question and sharing formula.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(OR(Sheet1!A1="?",Sheet2!A1="?",Sheet3!A1="?"),"Check","")
```

I think this format is going to be the quickest way to do it with a formula.