# How do I count the number of times a value is repeated across different files?

Tags: vba, excel, count

I want to know the number of times a value is repeated, for example 288, and how many values there are in total (every number) in many files with the same format.

For one worksheet I would just use `=COUNTIF(F:F;288)` and `=COUNTA(F:F)`

But now I have to do it with more than 30000 xlsx files inside a folder.

My first intent was to merge them into one file [like this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_windows8/copy-sheets-from-many-workbooks-found-in-a-folder/e9852c3f-7153-4262-9c73-1c9c1695757d?rtAction=1497601001600) and then count with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919461/excel-using-countif-countifs-across-multiple-sheets-same-column), but it stopped after 5279 tabs, I guess for some kind of limitation.

All my files are in the same folder (`H:\Macro\positions`) and the values are only expected in column `F`.

There are between 100-600 values per file, around 30000 files.

The operation has to be done just once, I don't mind waiting some hours for it to finish.

How would you do it?

Comment: Are all the xlsx in the same folder, and are the values expected only in column F in each sheet in each file in that folder?

Comment: Yes, H:\Macro\positions and just in column F.

Comment: How many values have to be counted? I mean 30000 Files are alot. opening excel files takes a lot of time, thats why you should merge them in some way. you could cycle trough the merged files then and store the counter in an array.

Comment: There are between 100-600 values per file, around 30000 files. The operation has to be done just once, I don't mind waiting some hours for it to finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below and follow the comments - basically the code opens each spreadsheet in the given folder, loops through the sheets in that workbook, runs your `COUNTIF` formula for each sheet and keeps a record of the total count.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckForValue()

    Dim objFso As FileSystemObject '<-- add Microsoft Scripting Runtime as a reference
    Dim objFile As File
    Dim wbToCheck As Workbook
    Dim wsToCheck As Worksheet
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim varValue As Variant
    Dim lngValueCount As Long
    Dim lngTotal As Long
    Dim wsf As WorksheetFunction

    On Error Goto CleanUp

    strPath = "H:\Macro\positions"
    Set objFso = New FileSystemObject '<-- access to file system
    varValue = 288 '<-- value you are looking for
    lngTotal = 0 '<-- total count of value you are looking for
    Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction '<-- shortcut to WorksheetFunction

    ' iterate files in folder
    For Each objFile In objFso.GetFolder(strPath).Files
        ' only check spreadsheets
        If objFile.Type = "Microsoft Excel Worksheet" Then
            ' get reference to workbook
            Set wbToCheck = Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path)
            ' iterate worksheets
            For Each wsToCheck In wbToCheck.Worksheets
                ' your original formula
                lngValueCount = wsf.CountIf(wsToCheck.Range("F:F"), varValue)
                ' add to total
                lngTotal = lngTotal + lngValueCount
            Next wsToCheck
            ' close without saving changes
            wbToCheck.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
    Next objFile

    ' final count of value you are looking for
    Debug.Print "Total is: " & lngTotal

CleanUp:
    ' error handling
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print Err.Description
    End If

    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Based on your comment that *The operation has to be done just once, I don't mind waiting some hours for it to finish* then the above code will do that, just grinding through sheets checking for the value. If you want to improve the speed you can use the following code before the `For` loop to help:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

And then afterward turn the settings back (after the `CleanUp:` statement):

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: I tried it and worked for a small sample. I will now use it with my 30000 files and let you know if it scaled well. Thank you very much.

Comment: Reading the edit now, perfect, I will use the speed up.

Comment: I corrected the edit - the code to turn the settings back on should be in the CleanUp block in case there is an error. I also added an `On Error Goto CleanUp` command.

Comment: It has finished now! Perfect. I will modify the code to count other values, the total number etc, but now I know how to do it. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem - glad it helped.